# why this jquery code not work, and will it also work if i had to load a .jsp file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, refresh

I have created a next.html and added the jquery.min.js file in the same folder but the still doesn't work. there is nothing in my next.html apart from a sentence in plane text.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>refresh</title>
</head>
<script src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <button name="button" id="button">reload</button>
    <div name="button" id="auto"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#button").click(function() {
                $("#auto").load("next.html");
             });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what happens in the *browsers **developer** tools console* do you get any error or any informative feedback from your browser? What browser are you using? What http server are you using? what happens if you navigate directly to next.html

Comment: My guess for browser is *Chrome*, my guess for http server is *None, using file:// protocol*

Comment: Are both `next.html`  and `jquery-1.12.4.min.js` files located in the **exact** same directory as this HTML file?

Comment: im using chrome, and the only thing visible on the screen is a button. http server would be tomcat 6. if i directly navigate to next.html the text within it is visible.

Comment: and yes all the files are with in the same folder

Comment: the code works when i run it in the eclipse environment.. but in the browser not so much

Comment: nothing to 'jsp' tag

Comment: if i give a .jsp file in the load command it does not run. please give me a solution

Comment: and the output is all messed up.. even if i change the text inside the next.html the out put is still the same